# Testing Jquery selector with Jasmine unit tests

Tags: jquery, jasmine

```
$('.froala > div > div > div > p').each(function (index, element) {
                        if ($(element).text() !== '') {
                            wordCount += $(element).text().split(' ').length;
                        }
                    });
```

I have this code that gets all the < p > tags in the froala editor and counts them. I need to write a Jasmine unit test to cover this and I don't have a clue how to do that. Maybe I could use a spyOn and return an array of < p > tags...

```
spyOn($('.froala > div > div > div > p'), 'each').and.returnValue([all, my, tags, here]);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: In ideal world you should not use jquery inside Jasmine tests at all. You need to test javasript objects methods. Otherwise you should use Jasmine together with PhantomJs and Karma to run your tests on real application without stubbing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be writing tests to test jQuery, and jasmine is not meant to test the dom. You should only write tests for your own code, and have deterministic input/output.

```
    var myFunction = function(index, element) {
                                if ($(element).text() !== '') {
                                    wordCount += $(element).text().split(' ').length;
                                } 
                      }
     var jquerySelector = ".froala > div > div > div > p";

     $(jquerySelector).each(myFunction });
```

Then write jasmine tests that import above file and have the expected froala html

```
var wordCount = 0;
var testhtml = '<div class="froala"><div><div><div><p>one</p><p>two</p></div></div></div></div>';

 $(testhtml).find(jquerySelector).each(myFunction)
 expect( wordCount ).toEqual(2)
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing it similar to how you mentioned by passing my own mocked html into a scope function and testing the scope function separate.

Comment: I also found this very helpful for anyone doing something similar in the future https://testdrivenwebsites.com/2010/07/29/html-fixtures-in-jasmine-using-jasmine-jquery/