# jasmine testing to get specific id - rest api

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to do jasmine testing on REST API. Although i am having loads of trouble with it. In this examplei am trying to test a search function to get 1 particular staffs name and id. However it is saying `getStaff is not defined`, but i think i have defined it. Below is the code

Test JS

```
describe("Spy on ajax call", function(){
it("should make an AJAX request with correct setting",
  function(){
    spyOn($, "ajax");
   getStaff(123, processResponse);
    expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        type:"GET",
        url:"http:URL/staffs + 123",
        dataType: "json",
        success: processResponse
    });
});
});
```

Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
    function getStaff(id, callBack){
    var id = $("#Staff_Id").val();
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "admin.php/staffs/" + id,
        success: showResponse,
        error: showError
    });
    };
});
});
```

I am in desperate need of help, can anyone help me please.

Comment: your jasemine is an "own" application which knows nothing about your `getStaff()` method

Comment: @messerbill i have linked them both in the html though. How do i get it to know about the method?

Comment: The problem is you have no visibility over this method. To achieve that, you could define this method on `window`. But I guess the best option is to install a faker server to respond your ajax calls.

Comment: @dloeda i dont know what you mean? i have the jasmine files/libraries downloaded and linked in the spec runner.html. Why do i need to install a faker server? i have a php file and a database

Comment: @dloeda has hit the point....and this is also exactly why i am not a friend of frontend testing

Comment: @messerbill i dont know what he means, I am completely new to all of this and dont have a clue how to fix it

Comment: you defined the `getStaff()` method in another context (the one of your app) - your test does not take a note of that definition. This means you'd have to append the functions definition to your `window` object (due to this is visible for jasmine). The other solution is to create a kind of a "fake server" which can be accessed to get your test data. And what i want to say is that such activities come with a great potential of doing any mistakes and therefore i got rid of those frontend tests one day...They produce a lot of more work for nearly no advantages...

Comment: thank you for explaining. I think I will go with the first option, as I havent heard my teacher talk about the second option. How do I define getStaff() to the window? I have to do tests, its for an assignment unfortunately

Comment: @messerbill would you please be able to help me?

Comment: @CD6554 have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468165/testing-jquery-selector-with-jasmine-unit-tests

Comment: @messerbill I looked at that question about a week and a half ago, but I don't understand it

Comment: The answer sais: Don't make use of `DOM tests`. Only test your input / output values (means that you only have to test your ajax requests)

Comment: @messerbill I know but I need to test the whole function. Its part of the requirements

Comment: who requires this? He / She should do it by him / herself. I see no value in testing DOM elements

Comment: it is for an assignment, I don't either but my lecture said we need to do it this way

Comment: @messerbill do you have any idea how i can test this entire function?